# How to Capture Return Value in FormData Object

Tags: php, ajax

I am uploading a file using FormData as following

```
<script>


var form = document.forms.namedItem("excelForm");
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {


  oData = new FormData(form);

oData.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", "excel", true);
oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
    if (oReq.status == 200) {
        $("#downloadButton").attr("style", "visibility: visible;")
        alert(oReq.response)
    } else {

    alert(oReq.status)


     }
    };

  oReq.send(oData);
  ev.preventDefault();
}, false);
</script>
```

and this will call a php function and that function will return a vlue so I want to capture that value I used oReq.response to capture that return value but it did not work

this is my php function

```
     public function actionexcel()
    {

        //.........
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

//                re write the excel file
                $fileName =$date. basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
                $newFile = $this->RewriteExcel($fileName);

               return $fileName;



            } else {
                echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **JavaScript**:

```
var form = document.forms.namedItem("excelForm");
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev){
    oData = new FormData(this);
    oData.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onreadystatechange= function(oEvent){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            $("#downloadButton").attr("style", "visibility: visible;")
            alert(this.responseText)
        } else {
            alert(this.status);
        }
    };
    oReq.send(oData);
    ev.preventDefault();
}, false); 

// ensure that your php file is in the correct directory and is using '.php'
oReq.open("POST", "./excel.php");
// don't forget to send
oReq.send();
```

In your **PHP** file:

```
// your class and method goes here
public function actionexcel(){ ... }
echo $class->actionexcel();
```